# How to avoid GTM from firing duplicate purchase events?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

On my website, there's a purchase event that's already configured for the usual purchase flow, but the website also allows for amendments of the purchase at a later stage. However, in the amendment flow, the site will first have to redirect to the purchase confirmation page which caused the purchase event to fire, hence duplicate purchase event.

Tried creating an exception trigger using document.referrer but seem to no avail, because it then won't capture the actual amendment afterward.

Any suggestions to avoid the duplicate event firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side you could save the `transaction ID` in the browser and read it from GTM. In this article you will find how to do it with a `customTask`:

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/prevent-google-analytics-duplicate-transactions-with-customtask/